# Google Docs API: update google document with changes made to python document body dict

Tags: google-docs-api

Using the python google docs client packages I have successfully gotten a representation of the body of a document I wrote (see snippet just below)

```
doc = service.documents().get(documentId=document_id).execute()
```

, but in the documentation I only see `batchUpdate` as the option to upload changes.

My question is, can I modify the contents (specifically the `paragraphStyle` or `textStyle`) of the python dictionary representation I get for a google doc, and then re-upload it somehow ?

This shows part of the dictionary that I want to edit, just for completeness.

```
[
  {
    "endIndex": 1,
    "sectionBreak": {
      "sectionStyle": {
        "columnSeparatorStyle": "NONE",
        "contentDirection": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT",
        "sectionType": "CONTINUOUS"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "startIndex": 1,
    "endIndex": 7,
    "paragraph": {
      "elements": [
        {
          "startIndex": 1,
          "endIndex": 7,
          "textRun": {
            "content": "Title\n",
            "textStyle": {}
          }
        }
      ],
      "paragraphStyle": {
        "namedStyleType": "NORMAL_TEXT",
        "direction": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT"
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `My question is, can I modify the contents (specifically the paragraphStyle or textStyle) of the python dictionary representation I get for a google doc, and then re-upload it somehow ?`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Hi there, I guess the motivation is that I find the methods laid out for formatting text (https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/format-text) with batchUpdate have me confused, but I thought perhaps I could update the styles in the python dict representation of the document body, and then upload that somehow? I hope that gives some more information.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. You want to update a Google Document without using the batchUpdate method. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: correct! I have a bit of knowledge about update a generic google drive file (like a .json text file for instance), but I don't know how I would use the google docs api to do a full update to a doc which might include changes to text and styles without the batchUpdate.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the current stage, unfortunately, it seems that the Google Document including the text body with the styles still cannot be created using the method of documents.create in Google Docs API. In this case, it is required to use the method of documents.batchUpdate. But from your replying, it seems that you want to update Google Document without using the method of documents.batchUpdate.

Comment: So as the current workaround, how about using Document Service of Google Apps Script? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document) If you want to see the sample scripts, you can see them in Stackoverflow. If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: From what you are mentioning, the `batchUpdate` seems to be right approach. However, it is not clear what exactly you want to achieve - would you mind providing more information? What kind of update do you want to make? @LiBrary

Comment: thanks for all the help @Tanaike, I'll keep looking. I might just be out of luck, but in any case I appreciate your time and consideration.

Comment: I got cut off in the last comment, so I'll try to continue here.

@ale13, maybe I can clarify further. If the current state of the document is DocA, and my goal for the document is to change the text and formatting in a single upload making DocB. I wanted to know if I could apply changes to the python dict representation of the document body that I get using the `service` object, and then make use of some update mechanism different than batchUpdate to update my entire document based on the python dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, how about using the Web Apps created by Google Apps Script as an API? In this case, Document service can be used. So I think that your uploaded JSON data to the Web Apps by python script can be parsed and used for Google Document. Is this direction the same with your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike that's certainly a direction I'd be alright going in. I guess it still seems weird to me that I can't make a batchUpdate that inserts formatted text, only one or the other thing at a time.

Comment: About `I guess it still seems weird to me that I can't make a batchUpdate that inserts formatted text, only one or the other thing at a time.`, can you provide the sample situation and the request body you tried?

Comment: @Tanaike, I just tried putting an example together and you know what? Everything with batchUpdate worked, so I think I will just learn to work with that api and close this issue. Also I'm so happy I found all your github gists related to the google api's you're a life saver!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users how have the same issue.